# how to get a specfic value form httpClient response in Razorpages

Tags: json, .net-core, httpclient, httpresponse, razor-pages

`return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

This line of code returns me a response from API which is fine but I want a specific object only, how can i do that

```cs
using (var _client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        var gettokenasyn = await GetTokenAsync();
        //_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(gettokenasyn);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", gettokenasyn);
        var body = new StringContent(JsonConvert
                    .SerializeObject(payproModels), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = await _client.PostAsync(endPointForOrder, body);
        return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        return exp.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the specific object as a json string or map it to a class?

Comment: You have to post  json you got from request and  json you want to get

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json string to a `JsonDocument` and then access the json properties.

Let's say you have this sample json response and you want to take the speed value:

```
{
  "speed": 4,
  "deg": 95,
  "gust": 3.27
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync(endPointForOrder, body);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using (var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(stream))
{
    JsonElement speed = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("speed");
    return speed.GetDouble();
}
```

Alternative you can create a class and deserialize the json to an instance of that class:

```
public class Wind
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public int Deg { get; set; }
    public double Gust { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync(endPointForOrder, body);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

var wind = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Wind>(stream);
return wind.Speed;
```

You also need to import System.Text.Json namespace:

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0